# Nuxt Efficient Cache

Tags: caching, nuxt.js, workbox

*Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy*. I get this if I audit my app. I added this code to nuxt.config but this would help.

```
render: {
  static: {
    maxAge: 2592000
  }
},
```

its by default caching static assets 1h in browser. **Where can I change it. or How?**

Comment: Are you sure lighthouse is complaining about your own files, and not 3rd party files?  Often things like Stripe or Intercom get flagged by Lighthouse as being served without an efficient cache policy, despite there being nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Yes they are my own files i can reach them by mywebsite.com/img/image.jpg

Comment: are you running an reverse proxy infront of your nuxt app? if yes your reverse proxy could add an cache control header to it

Comment: no i use static generate and host on firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure your headers for your static files with Firebase:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers

```
// in firebase.json
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "headers" attribute within "hosting", override cache control
  "headers": [ {
    "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
    "headers": [ {
      "key": "Cache-Control",
      "value": "max-age=2592000"
    } ]
  }
 ]
}
```

This should give you the desired cache control values, depending on what you want to set there.